# Пожалуйста помогите с выводом данных авторизованного пользователя

Tags: php

Пожалуйста помогите с вопросом вывода данных авторизованного пользователя.

1. Имеется авторизация

   ```
   <?php

   // Страница авторизации

   # Функция для генерации случайной строки

   function generateCode($length=6) {
       $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHI JKLMNOPRQSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
       $code = "";
       $clen = strlen($chars) - 1;  
       while (strlen($code) < $length) {
               $code .= $chars[mt_rand(0,$clen)];  
       }

       return $code;
   }

   # Соединямся с БД

   require_once "db.php";

   if(isset($_POST['login_submit']))
   {
       # Вытаскиваем из БД запись, у которой логин равняеться введенному
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_password FROM users WHERE user_login='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login_login'])."' LIMIT 1");

       $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

       # Сравниваем пароли
       if($data['user_password'] === md5(md5($_POST['login_password'])))
       {
           # Генерируем случайное число и шифруем его
           $hash = md5(generateCode(10));

           if(!@$_POST['not_attach_ip'])
           {
               # Если пользователя выбрал привязку к IP
               # Переводим IP в строку
               $insip = ", user_ip=INET_ATON('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')";
           }

           # Записываем в БД новый хеш авторизации и IP
           mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_hash='".$hash."' ".$insip." WHERE user_id='".$data['user_id']."'");

           # Ставим куки
           setcookie("id", $data['user_id'], time()+60*60*24*30);
           setcookie("hash", $hash, time()+60*60*24*30);

           # Переадресовываем браузер на страницу проверки нашего скрипта
           header("Location: check.php"); exit();
       }
       else
       {
           print "Неправильный логин/пароль";
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```
2. Имеется регистрация

   ```
   <?php
   // Страница регситрации нового пользователя

   # Соединямся с БД
   require_once "db.php";

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
       $err = array();

       # проверям логин
       if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/",$_POST['reg_login']))
       {
       //    $err[] = "Логин может состоять только из букв английского алфавита и цифр";
       }

     //  if(strlen($_POST['reg_login']) < 3 or strlen($_POST['reg_login']) > 30)
     //  {
     //     $err[] = "Логин должен быть не меньше 3-х символов и не больше 20";

     //  }

       # проверяем, не сущестует ли пользователя с таким именем
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE user_login='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reg_login'])."'");
       if(mysql_result($query, 0) > 0)
       {
           $err[] = "Логин занят";
       }

       # Если нет ошибок, то добавляем в БД нового пользователя
       if(count($err) == 0)
       {
           $login = $_POST['reg_login'];

           # Убераем лишние пробелы и делаем двойное шифрование
           $password = md5(md5(trim($_POST['reg_password'])));
           $name = $_POST['name'];
           $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
           $birthdate_day = $_POST['birthdate_day'];
           $birthdate_month = $_POST['birthdate_month'];
           $birthdate_year = $_POST['birthdate_year'];
           $sex = $_POST['sex'];
           $e_mail = $_POST['e_mail'];

           mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET user_login='".$login."', user_password='".$password."', name='".$name."', firstname='".$firstname."', birthdate_day='".$birthdate_day."', birthdate_month='".$birthdate_month."', birthdate_year='".$birthdate_year."', sex='".$sex."', e_mail='".$e_mail."'");

            // $id = $_COOKIE['id'];
           header("Location: index.php"); exit();
       }
     //  else
     //  {
         // print "<b>При регистрации произошли следующие ошибки:</b><br>";
         //  foreach($err AS $error)
      //     {
         //      print $error."<br>";
      //     }
     //  }
   }
   ?>
   ```
3. И проверка авторизации с перенаправлением на личную страницу пользователя `(profile.php?id=".$id.")`, где `$id = $_COOCKIE['id'];`

Пожалуйста помогите реализовать вывод заполненных при регистрации пользователем данных на его личную страницу (site.ru/profile.php?id=1).
Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Вы вести её на этой странице, проверив авторизацию (сессия в куках + ip запроса например)?...а так вопрос не очень ясен.

Comment: **Личная** страница пользователя `profile.php` не нуждается в параметре `id`.

Answer (score -1):

Вообще, все просто.
Соединяешься с БД, по id вытаскиваешь нужную информацию о пользователе и выводишь её.

Например,

```
<?php
//получаешь id из массива GET
$id = $_GET['id'];

//соединяешься с бд (сам оформишь)
//делаешь запрос по id
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='.$id.' LIMIT 1';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$result_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

//и выводишь
echo $result_assoc['name'].', добро пожаловать!';
?>
```

Comment: Т.е. легитимность запроса и доступа, и доступа именно к этой странице проверить не надо?

Comment: А что, в вопросе написано "проверить, является ли пользователь зарегистрированным"? Вопрос звучит "как вывести" - ответ звучит "вот так вывести". Зачем усложнять?

Comment: Затем, что видно, что человек не очень опытный и более развернутый ответ и подсказки натолкнут его на разные мысли. Но это моё мнение и прошу прощение, может я его слишком прямо высказал.

Comment: Очень плохой ответ! 1. Пример содержит SQL Injection. 2. mysql_* в текущих версиях PHP не поддерживаются. 3. Выбран не тот пользователь который залогинен, а тот чьё id передали как параметр.